# How do I copy files from old iMac (2009) to usb using single user mode if I can't remember the exact names of the files?

Tags: imac

My old iMac (2009) won't boot and can't be repaired in single user mode. I want to back up a few files before rebooting, but can't remember the exact name of the files. Is there a command that copies all files, or is there a way of seeing what is on the harddrive?

Answer (score 1):

First open a terminal. There you can do all things you would do with Finder.

The Terminal offers a range of commands you can use:

- To see, what is in the current directory, run `ls`.
- To copy a file, use `cp <from> <to>` (and replace  and  with the correct filenames or paths)
- To see where disks are mounted, you can use `df`, `mount` or `ls /Volumes`
- To change folders use `cd <foldername>`

You don't need to fully type out all filenames. You can use autocomplete using the Tab key.